Unable to contact an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for the domain
image
I created an AD DS server for a machine to connect to with the domain name.
It shows this message, but I set everything correctly.
Machine IP: 10.1.1.1
Server AD DS: 10.1.1.1
DNS: 10.1.1.2

For AD to work correctly, the DNS server should be in the AD DS.
